# Nested Routes in React Router v4

Tags: react-router, react-router-v4

I'm trying to set up some nested routes to add a common layout. Check the code out:

```
  <Router>
    <Route component={Layout}>
      <div>
        <Route path='/abc' component={ABC} />
        <Route path='/xyz' component={XYZ} />
      </div>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

While this works perfectly fine, I still get the warning:

> Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same
>   route;  will be ignored

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 83):

CESCO's answer renders first the component `AppShell` **then** one of the components inside  `Switch`. But these components are NOT going to render inside `AppShell`, they will NOT be children of `AppShell`.

In v4 to wrap components you don't put anymore your `Route`s inside another `Route`, you put your `Route`s directly inside a component.
I.E : for the wrapper instead of `<Route component={Layout}>` you directly use `<Layout>`.

Full code :

```
  <Router>
    <Layout>
      <Route path='/abc' component={ABC} />
      <Route path='/xyz' component={XYZ} />
    </Layout>
  </Router>
```

The change is probably explained by the idea to make React Router v4 to be pure 
React so you only use React elements like with any other React element.

EDIT : I removed the `Switch` component as it's not useful here. See when it's useful [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/Switch.md).

Comment: Thanks!  Wrapping it like:  `<Layout><Switch><Route/></Switch></Layout>` worked for me :)

Comment: No problem. If you use a single `Route` you do NOT need `Switch`. `Switch` is like the || operator : the first `Route` inside a `Switch` statement that match path is rendered but the other `Route`s inside the `Switch` are NOT rendered. I added a link to the doc of `Switch` in my comment.

Comment: Thanks, It's very useful.

Comment: Great solution. I

Comment: Thanks, this helped me to better understand and solve the problem.

Comment: what if you wanted another Route element which is NOT wrapped with layout? I'm struggling all day today to make it work and can't find proper way (example: ABC, XYZ are pages after you logged in, so they need Layout which contains sidebar, menu, etc, but you also need a Route for login page which doesn't need menus)

Comment: How would one get a _location_ object or _location.pathname_ inside of Layout component (ie. `this.props.location.pathname`)?

Comment: Why isn't this common knowledge! (Maybe it is now, but still had to search a fair amount to find it) - thank you, sir.

Answer (score 10):

You need to use the switch component to nesting to work nice. Also, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254929/how-to-nest-routes-in-react-router-v4)

```
// main app
<div>
    // not setting a path prop, makes this always render
    <Route component={AppShell}/>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={AsyncDashboard(userAgent)}/>
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
    </Switch>
</div>
```

And version-4 components do not take children, instead, you should use the render prop.

```
<Router>
    <Route render={(props)=>{
      return <div>Whatever</div>}>
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
<Router>
    <Layout>
        <Route path='/abc' component={ABC} />
        <Route path='/xyz' component={XYZ} />
    </Layout>
</Router>
```

Comment: When you add the answer, add some explanation so that its useful for others. However +1 for answering it first

Comment: Not a useful comment. Giving an example doesn't always help.

Comment: This seems to work with `BrowserRouter` instead of `Router` too.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want `Layout` to run at loaded. Use this method:

```
<div className="container">
    <Route path="/main" component={ChatList}/>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Start} />
        <Route path="/main/single" component={SingleChat} />
        <Route path="/main/group" component={GroupChat} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

Whenever history changes, **componentWillReceiveProps** in the ChatList will run.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this :

```
<Route exact path="/Home"
                 render={props=>(
                                 <div>
                                      <Layout/>
                                      <Archive/>
                                </div>
                       )} 
    />
```