# How to nest routes in React Router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Is there a way to nest routes in React Router v4?

This works:

```
  <Router basename='/app'>
    <main>
      <Route path='/' component={AppBar} />
      <Route path='/customers' component={Customers} />
    </main>
  </Router>
```

This does not:

```
  <Router basename='/app'>
    <Route path='/' component={AppBar}>
      <Route path='/customers' component={Customers} />
    </Route>
  </Router>
```

**Customers Component:**

```
import React, { Component, PropTypes } from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'

export default class Customers extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Container>
        <h1>Customers</h1>
      </Container>
    )
  }
}

const Container = styled.section`
  height: 100%;
  padding: 15px;
  overflow: auto;
`
```

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode, I'm mainly trying to see if there is a way to avoid needing a wrapper (i.e. `<main>`) because `<Router>` can only have one child.

Comment: are you getting an error, cause I do exactly your 'does not' and it works fine.

Comment: In the second example, the `Customers` component does not render.

Comment: Can you post your Customers Component?

Comment: @ExperimentsWithCode, Posted.

Comment: Do you have a `{children}` tag in AppBar component?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Best pattern I have found so far.

```
// main app
<div>
    // not setting a path prop, makes this always render
    <Route component={AppShell}/>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard" component={AsyncDashboard(userAgent)}/>
        <Route component={NoMatch}/>
    </Switch>
</div>
```

I can just keep nesting this inside a component and everything works nice including hmr(If using webpack, dont forget to set `output.publicPath` to `"/"`)

```
// dashboard component
<div>
    // the same way as before, not setting a path prop
    // makes it render on every /dashboard/** request 
    <Route component={DashboardTAB}/>
    <Switch>
        // longer path (with same root) than others first
        <Route path="/dashboard/graphs/longerpath" component={GraphForm}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard/graphs" component={Graphs}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard/workers" component={List}/>
        <Route path="/dashboard/insert" component={InsertComponent}/>
    </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: I did like that but with a master parent layout, that's running correctly without error but showing the first route in <switch> only (in the component), and no page change when i click a link, im using webpack too and put  output.publicPath as you said.. any idea for another issue ? thx

Comment: Perfect that's alright, i just started the first route with the shortest path so that took the shortest path as the only one available.

Comment: Not setting path prop solved the problem I was having. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

I adapted this from the docs, seem to work so far. Probably missing something obvious, and yes it is not the v4 way but we need all the routes defined in one place.

```
function RouteNest(props){ return (
  <Route exact={props.exact} path={props.path} render={ p => <props.component {...p} children={props.children}/> } />
)}

export const MainRoutes = props => 

<div className='content layout'>

  <Route exact path="/" component={Landing}/>
  <Route  path={'/contact'} component={Contact}/>

  <RouteNest  path={'/thing'} component={CompoWithSub}>
    <RouteNest  path={'/thing/suba'} component={SubComponentA}/>
    <RouteNest  path={'/thing/subb'} component={SubComponentB}/>
  </RouteNest>


</div>

export const CompoWithSub = props => <div>{props.children)</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You're AppBar component is in charge of rendering Customers. For customers to be called, you have to render the children of AppBar. Anything directly nested under AppBar is a child of AppBar.

```
import React from 'react';

const AppBar = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
    <header>
       <h1> stuff </h1>
    </header>
    {children}
  </div>
);

export default AppBar
```

Please note that only AppBar will render when you visit "/". AppBar and Customers will render when you visit "/customers".

Comment: Even with rendering `<AppBar />`'s `{ children }`, the `<Customers />` component does not render when nested in React Router v4.

Comment: and you are at the url "/customers" ?

Comment: Yes. `/app/customers`.  When not nested, the `<Customers />` component does render at that URL.

Comment: well shit. I thought I was on v4, but I'm on v3. Sorry about that. Not sure what changes between the two versions.

Comment: The only reference to nested routes in the docs is this: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#match but I just don't understand how it can be used to build nested routes.

Comment: Actually there is another example using route config: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/examples/route-config but I'd rather not use route config

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah if you were able to use the route-config example to get nesting to work, could you post some example code?  I have tried to emulate it as closely as possible, and I still can't seem to get the simple behavior once gotten with v3 nested routes to render properly in v4.

Comment: @capouch, No success so far. I'm currently using a wrapper element but I'm not happy about it.

Answer (score 1):

If someone wants to have nested routes without typing prefix of wrapper route I've created something like this in TSX:

Imports:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { Route, RouteComponentProps, RouteProps, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import Index from 'views/index';
import Login from 'views/login';
import NoMatch from 'views/no-match';
```

Interfaces:

```
interface INestedRoutes {
    nested?: string;
}

interface INestedRoute extends RouteProps, INestedRoutes {}
```

NestedRoute and NestedRoutes wrapper:

```
class NestedRoutes extends React.Component<INestedRoutes> {
    public render() {
        const childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(this.props.children, (child) => {
            return React.cloneElement(
                child as React.ReactElement<any>, { nested: this.props.nested },
            );
        })
        return childrenWithProps;
    }
}


const NestedRoute: React.SFC<INestedRoute> = (props: INestedRoute) => {
    return <Route path={`${props.nested}${props.path}`} component={props.component} />;
};
```

And routes with wrapper:

```
const MultiLanguage: React.SFC<RouteComponentProps<any>> = (props: RouteComponentProps<any>) => {
    return (
        <NestedRoutes nested={props.match.path} >
            <NestedRoute path="/test" component={Login} />
            <NestedRoute path="/no-match" component={NoMatch} />
        </NestedRoutes>
    );
};


export default (
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/:language" component={MultiLanguage}/>
        <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route component={NoMatch} />
    </Switch>
);
```

Answer (score 0):

For nested routes there is a very simple way which i using.

Example main router is be like that

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch >
    <Route path="/" component={Home}></Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Inside Home component using Nested Routing be like:

```
<div className="App">
  <Navbar title="Home" links = { NavbarLinks }/>
  {this.renderContentPage()}
</div>
```

renderContentPage will check the URL and render the nested route.

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Page1}></Route>
<Route exact path="/page1" component={Page1}></Route>
<Route exact path='/page2' component={Page2} />
```

So inside Home component page1 and page2 components rendered.

Answer (score 0):

Route expects a single children i.e. a component.
It should not be a new Route.
What you can do is to include your nested routes inside your customers component.

Also make sure to remove exact inside the routes in customers component.