# ReactJS Router Not Routing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Working on getting React-Router working for an SPA but I can't seem to get it to render anything other than the App component.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, Link, IndexRoute, browserHistory } from 'react-router';
import Parameter from './components/parameter/Parameter';

class App extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
                <Link to="/parameter">Click Me!</Link>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class Test extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>TEST PAGE</h1>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

var routes = (
    <Route name="root" component={App} path="/">
        <Route component={Test} path="test" />
        <Route component={Parameter} path="parameter" />
    </Route>
)

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes} />
), document.getElementById('react'))
```

Comment: What version of react-router?

Comment: "react-router": "^3.0.2"

Comment: Have you tried adding the `/` for `/test` and `/parameter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't specifying where you want the nested components to render within the `App` component. The `App` component behaves something like a layout for all nested routes.

The components you specify for nested routes need a place to go within a layout / parent component when a particular route is hit.

The simplest way to get this working is to use `{this.props.children}` somewhere in your `App` component. Refer to my example below.

**Here is your App component again:**

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h1>TEST</h1>
                <Link to="/parameter">Click Me!</Link>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

For a more in-depth example, refer to the [active-links](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/active-links/app.js) example from the react-router repo. In their example, you can see that `children` is available as props within the `App` component and will render any of the other components from nested routes when a relevant route is hit. For example, hitting the `/` route will render the `Index` component within `App` where `{children}` is positioned because there is a directly nested route `<IndexRoute ... />` that exists.

React provides `this.props.children` as a way to access a component's children. It allows you to pass components as data to another component. In this case, rendering the child component within the `App` component.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using React Router v4, I think the reason the nested components are not rendering is because you can't nest `<Route />`s in React Router v4.

I opened up a question on this earlier:

[How to nest routes in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254929/how-to-nest-routes-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: I am using React Router 3