# React-router-dom v4 nested routes not working

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

In reference to the unresolved question (as a final conclusion)

- [Multiple Nested Routes in react-router-dom v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42984597/multiple-nested-routes-in-react-router-dom-v4)
- [How to nest routes in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254929/how-to-nest-routes-in-react-router-v4)

I am also getting the same issue.

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start promotes `react-router-dom`

Also, people find better to `list down routes` in one file rather inside components.

**Something referred:** https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-config

**Something working (mostly):**

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


export const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <MainApp path="/">
          <Route path="/list" component={List}/>
          <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
        </MainApp>
        <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

**Something not working:**
`site.com/SomeGarbagePath`  shows the `<MainApp>` I think.
`<Route path="*" component={PageNotFound}/>`

**Update**

```
/ - Home - parent of all (almost)
/List - inside home
/Settings - inside home
/Login - standalone
/Users - inside home, For now just showing itself. It has further pages.
/User/123 - inside user with /:id
/User/staticUser - inside user with static route
/garbage - not a route defined (not working as expected)
```

Comment: It isn't clear what you are asking. Please give some examples of what your routes should be, and how you want your routes to behave.

Comment: @ToddChaffee  Login page is standalone. The `/` wants to render header, footer and some other content in between header and footer. Content is based on the router path (e.g `list` for `/list` and `settings` component for `/settings`. If no route matches, its a `pageNotFound`

Comment: @Masood - did you find any solution for this? For some reason the answer below doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is one way of doing what you described (note there are other ways of handling layouts directly in your React Components). In order to keep the example simple, the other components (`<Home>, <List>` etc.) are created as purely functional components with no properties or state but it would be trivial to put each one in its own file as a proper React component. The example below is complete and will run.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

class App extends Component {
  render() {

    const Header = () => <h1>My header</h1>;
    const Footer = () => <h2>My footer</h2>;
    const Login = () => <p>Login Component</p>;    
    const Home = () => <p>Home Page</p>;
    const List = () => <p>List Page</p>;
    const Settings = () => <p>Settings Page</p>;
    const PageNotFound = () => <h1>Uh oh, not found!</h1>;

    const RouteWithLayout = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
      return (
        <div>
          <Header />
          <Route {...rest} render={ () => React.createElement(component) } />
          <Footer />
        </div>
      );
    };

    return (
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <RouteWithLayout exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <RouteWithLayout path="/list" component={List} />
            <RouteWithLayout path="/settings" component={Settings} />
            <Route path="*" component={PageNotFound} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>    
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This will do the following, which is hopefully what is now described in your question:

1. `/login` has no header or footer.
2. `/`, `/list`, and `/settings` all have the header and footer.
3. Any route that is not found will display the `PageNotFound` component, with no header or footer.

Comment: Chafee, A) I do NOT want `/login` to have `Header`. Please let me know what fits my use case. B) I may or many not nest routes for few components and not for others (as shown in example)

Comment: There is no nesting of routes in your example, or at least it isn't clear. The way you are "nesting" routes, you have `/login` and then `/login/list` and `/login/settings`. What do you really want? Your question is so unclear. You need to give more examples in your question if you want help. Tell us WHY you want to nest routes. What BEHAVIOR are you trying to achieve. If you can tell us that, maybe we can help.

Comment: Todd Chaffee  I NEVER stated /login/list. If you observe A) `react-router-dom v4`, Routes have components. B) see `<MainApp>` that does NOT have `/login` route. So the route is NOT `login/list` but its `/list`. This is not `v3`. For more elaboration: see `update`

Comment: Todd Chaffee, your solution is promising and working! However I wanted  some that had routes on a single file, nesting and still with react-router-dom-v4 way. I am accepting your solution as best comparatively so far. Thanks a lot for the great effort!

Answer (score 1):

I'll be honest, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. I'm assuming you're trying to get your "Something not working" example to work.

Something like this,

```
import * as React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'


export const Routes = () => (
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
        <MainApp path="/">
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/list" component={List}/>
            <Route path="/settings" component={Settings}/>
          </Switch>
        </MainApp>
        <Route component={PageNotFound} /> 
      </Switch>
    </div>
  </Router>
)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but its not working. Its showing the errorpage inside MainApp page (or not at all with <Switch> placement variations); when garbabe typed link.