# How do I pass Redux props to a separate component in a different Route with React Router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-redux

I'm creating a real time chat app with react, react router v4 and redux. The problem is that, as you may know, react router v4 changes a lot of stuff and **nesting routes** is not working for me.

So I have this code with a nested route **that is not working**:

```
<Route path='/' component={App}>
    <Route path="/user" component={AddUser}/>
</Route>
```

It's giving me this error `Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored`.

Where `component={App}`, in the first `<Route path='/'` is a redux connect:

```
const App = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header)
```

So my component `App` has all the the `props` I need. All works fine except by the fact that I need to pass those props from `App` to the nested route component `AddUser`.

**How do I pass the redux `props` to a separate component in a different `Route`?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

Comment: check this also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254929/how-to-nest-routes-in-react-router-v4

Comment: That question didn't solve my problem because it's not clear enough for me. I answered my own question below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With react-router v4 when we need nested routes, we don't nest Routes. Instead, we put them inside nested components. You can read about this more here: [Nested routes with react router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4)

In your case, you can put your "/user" route inside the App component and then use `render` instead of `component`. So you can pass your App props to AddUser as usual.

```
<Route path='/' component={App}/>
```

**App.js**

```
class App extends Component{
  //...
  render(){
    return(
      //....
      <Route path="/user"
        render={() => <AddUser myProp={this.props.myAppProp}/>}/>
      //....
    )
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution reading this blog post: https://medium.com/@5XvYrLT7/react-server-side-rendering-with-react-router-3-x-74cf87919b3

With react-router v4 you don’t do this any more, don’t nest :

```
<Route component={App}>
    <Route component={Index} />
    <Route component={About} />
</Route>
```

You do it like this now. App embeds your routes as-is:

```
<App>
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Index} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    </Switch>
</App>
```