# How to perform dynamic component rendering using react router v4?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have an application with a Login page followed by a Dashboard page. The routes that I've defined in the `index.js` are like this:

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

**Dashboard.js:**

```
return (
  <div>
    <Header/>
    <Footer/>
    <Switch>
     <Route path="/dashboard/content1" component={content1} />
     <Route path="/dashboard/content2" component={content2} />
    </Switch>
  </div>
);
```

The `Dashboard` component is rendering 3 of its child components. `Header`, `Footer` and `Content1`. I want the Dashboard component to render `Content1` by default (i.e. when the url is `/dashboard`) and also when the url is `/dashboard/content1`, and should render `content2` when the url is `/dashboard/content2`. `Header` & `Footer` components should remain. Please suggest the configuration for the `Dashboard` component to achieve the same.

Comment: in that case define `content1` and `content2` route inside `Dashboard` component, check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42254929/how-to-nest-routes-in-react-router-v4) for more details.

Comment: @MayankShukla I've updated my question with more details. Can you suggest something bit detailed please?

Answer (score 0):

In React-router v4 you provide Routes within the component, so you can write your Routes as follows

```
<Router>
  <div>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
  </div>
</Router>
```

and then in the Dashboard Component render method

```
render() {
    return (
        <div>
            {/* other content */}
            <Switch>
               <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={content1} />
               <Route path="/dashboard/content1" component={content1} />
               <Route path="/dashboard/content2" component={content2} />
            </Switch>
        </div>

    )

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a variant of an answer to your post before you have edited it, you can do it (nesting) like this:

```
<Router>
    <Header/>
    <Content1/>
    <Footer/>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Login}/>
        <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard/content1" component={content1} />
        <Route exact path="/dashboard/content2" component={content2} />
      </Switch>    
</Router>
```

Answer (score 0):

React-Router's `Switch` component renders the first thing that matches, 
so if you put a route without a path last, it will render that if no other routes match, essentially treating it as a default. Like so:

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header/>
        <Footer/>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard/content2" exact component={Content2} />
            <Route component={Content1} />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

I have found that rendering a component instead of a Route also works, although I dont know if it's officially supported.

```
return (
    <div>
        <Header/>
        <Footer/>
        <Switch>
            <Route path="/dashboard/content2" exact component={Content2} />
            <Content1 />
        </Switch>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: The ```<Content1 />``` component renders by default now(on ```/dashboard```) but hitting the ```/dashboard/content2``` url throws a 404 error.

Comment: And if you remove the `exact` prop?