# react router 4 nested components not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I am switching from react-router 3.x to 4.x and I am not able to render nested routes.

I bootstrapped an application using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app)

```
index.js file

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Routes from './routes';
import './index.css';

ReactDOM.render(<Routes />, document.getElementById('root'));

routes.js file

import React from 'react';
import _ from 'lodash';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import { dojoRequire } from 'esri-loader';
import EsriLoader from 'esri-loader-react';

import App from './components/App';
import Home from './components/Home';

/**
 * Helper component to wrap app
 */
class AppWrapper extends React.Component {
  /**
   * Util function to render the children
   * Whenever a state change happens in react application, react will render the component again
   * and we wish to pass the updated state to the children as props
   */
  renderChildren() {
    const {children} = this.props;
    if (!children) {
      return;
    }

    return React.Children.map(children, c => React.cloneElement(c, _.omit(this.props, 'children'), { }));
  }

  render() {
    const child = this.renderChildren();
    return (
      <App {...this.props}>
        {child}
      </App>
    );
  }
}

/**
 * Root Loader component to load esri api
 */
class LoaderComponent extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { loaded: false };
  }

  /**
   * Callback fired when arc GIS api is loaded
   * Now load the requirejs modules using dojorequire
   */
  esriReady() {
    dojoRequire(['esri/Map', 'esri/views/MapView'], (Map, MapView) => {
      this.setState({ Map, MapView, loaded: true });
    });
  }

  render() {
    const options = {
      url: 'https://js.arcgis.com/4.3/',
    };
    return (
      <div>
        <EsriLoader options={options} ready={this.esriReady.bind(this)} />
        <AppWrapper {...this.state}>
          <Route exact path="/home" component={Home} />
        </AppWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

const Routes = (props) => (
  <Router {...props}>
    <Route exact path="/" component={LoaderComponent} />
  </Router>
);

export default Routes;
```

App and home components are simple div tags that renders `<div>Hello world App</div>` and `<div>Hello world Home</div>`

The `App` component renders perfectly, but when I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/home` component I see an empty page.

**What I would like to do is**

When the user launched the app the user should be redirected to `/home` and I would like to define two additional routes for `App` Component

```
<Route exact path="/a" component={A} />
<Route exact path="/b" component={B} />
```

Currently I am not able to redirect to `/home` on app load and not able to define nested routes for `App` Component.

> NOTE: This above code was working fine for react-router version 3.x. To redirect on page load I would use `IndexRedirect`.

I already had a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095600/nested-routes-in-v4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41474134/nested-routes-with-react-router-v4) question and I tried all possible solutions in those questions but none is working.

**I would like to have all the route handling in `routes.js` file**.

Answer (score 3):

You could achieve such routing with `Switch` and `Redirect`:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, Switch, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom';

import {LoaderComponent, AppWrapper , Home, A, B} from './mycomponents';


const routes = (
  <LoaderComponent>
    <AppWrapper>
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => <Redirect to='/home' />} />
        <Route exact path='/home' component={Home} />
        <Route exact path='/a' component={A} />
        <Route exact path='/b' component={B} />
      </Switch>
    </AppWrapper>
  </LoaderComponent>
);

export default routes;
```

And use the `routes.js` file something like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import {Router} from 'react-router-dom';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';

import routes from './routes';


const history = createHistory();

const App = () =>
  <Router history={history}>
    {routes}
  </Router>;

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: You missed the `LoaderComponent`. It is required as I have to load some external api.

Comment: All the 3 components, Home, A, B should follow the hierarchy. `LoaderComponent -> App -> Home/A/B`

Comment: I updated my answer with the hierarchy. Since everything in react-router-4 is a component, you can define routes wherever you want, not only in 1 file (`routes.js`) if this isn't the structure you can organize your code.

Answer (score 1):

Hey I have implemented `react-router-v4`, for a simple sample project. here is the **github link :** [How to Implement the react-router-v4](https://github.com/AnuradhSC/reactrouterv4). please go through it. very simple.

to run : clone it and hit `npm install`. hope this will help to you.