# redirect to home after login react

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm new working with react v4 and I try to redirect to another page, something like a home page after the user authenticate in but I'm getting problems with nested routes, I've tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095600/nested-routes-in-react-router-v4) and [this in documentation](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/basic) but doesn't work the way that I need.

This is my index.js

```
ReactDOM.render((
    <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
            <Route path="/" component={Login}>
            <MuiThemeProvider>
                <div>
                    <div>
                        <SearchBar/>
                        <MainMenu/>
                    </div>
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/home" component={HomeAllSubjects}/>
                            <Route path="/calendar" component={UnderConstruction}/>
                            <Route path="/myPlan" component={UnderConstruction}/>
                            <Route path="/myWorks" component={MyWorks}/>
                            <Route path="/indicators" component={UnderConstruction}/>
                            <Route path="/myGroups" component={GroupsContacts}/>
                            <Route path="/eduteca" component={UnderConstruction}/>
                            <Route path="/notifications" component={HomeGroups}/>
                            <Route path="/miSer" component={UnderConstruction}/>
                            <Route path="/help" component={MyGroupsDescription}/>
                            <Route path="/topic" component={HomeSubject}/>
                            <Route path="/areaInfo" component={HomeUnit}/>
                            <Route path="/comments" component={CommentsList}/>
                            
                        </Switch>
                    <Footer/>
                </div>
            </MuiThemeProvider>
            </Route>
        </Router>
    </Provider>
), document.getElementById('content'));
```

And this is my Login.js render method

```
render()
{
    debugger;
    if (this.props.redirecter)
    {
        history.push('/home');

    }

    return (
        <div>
            <HeaderLogin/>
            <div style={{ marginLeft: '300px', padding: '100px'}}>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col-md-offset-5 col-md-3">
                            <form style={styles.formlogin} onSubmit={this.handleClick}>
                                {this.props.errorMessage ? <h5>{this.props.errorMessage}</h5> : null}


                                <input style={styles.formcontrol} type="text" className="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder='Usuario' onChange={this.onUserChange}/><br/>
                                {this.state.userMessage ? <span style={styles.mess}>{this.state.userMessage}</span> : null}
                                <br/>

                                <input style={styles.formcontrol} type="password" className="form-control input-sm chat-input" placeholder='Clave' onChange={this.onPasswordChange}/><br/>
                                {this.state.passMessage ? <span style={styles.mess}>{this.state.passMessage}</span> : null}
                                <br/>
                                <div style={styles.wrapper}>
                                <span className="group-btn">
                                    <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary btn-md" value="Submit" >Login</button>
                                </span>
                                </div>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <Footer/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

}

NOTE: when I put the Login route into the Swictch is working but when a put it outside appear this:

[errors in the browser console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Whsky.png)

Comment: Try adding `exact` to your login route like this `<Route path="/" exact component={Login}>`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer but I' ve tried that and doesn't work even the app don't load show this error in the console:  Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use exact in your route path.

`<Route exact path="/home" component={HomeAllSubjects}/>`

Btw, it's a good practice to separate the routes into a single file, try something like this in your index.js file:

```
import {Router, browserHistory} from 'react-router';
import routes from 'your routes file path';
ReactDOM.render(
 <div>
  <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={browserHistory} routes={routes}>
  </Provider>
 </div>
 , document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: puttiing "exact" to the route doesn't work, I already put the routes in a different file as you recommend but this way <Provider store={store}>
   <Router history={browserHistory} >{routes}</Provider> becouse as you say don't work and I can't redirect after login to home yet, thanks for answer

Comment: Can you send me the source code? I will try to solve it, but i need to see the entire code. Send me a message if you can.

Comment: thanks for your help, you can find the project [here](https://github.com/falzate81/LoginReact), thank you again.