# Can't render React Component using layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have `Navbar` which has to be rendered on every page. So I'm trying to get this through BrowserRouter like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import PublicLayout from './components/layouts/PublicLayout';
import Main from './components/pages/Main';
import Services from './components/pages/Services';

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="App">
                    <Route component={ PublicLayout }>
                        <Route exact path='/' component={ Main } />
                        <Route exact path='/services' component={ Services } />
                    </Route>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

My PublicLayout is just navigation links. And I see it on the screen. But React doesn't render the `Main page` content. What I expect to see it just Hello World from Main page component below Navbar. What I'm doing wrong? Please help.

**UPD:** My PublicLayout code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Navbar from '../nav/Navbar';

class PublicLayout extends Component {
    state = {
        items: [
            { id: 1, name: 'Услуги', link: '/services' },
        ]
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Navbar items={ this.state.items } />
                { this.props.children }
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PublicLayout;
```

**UPD2:** In browser console I see an error:

```
Warning: You should not use <Route component> and <Route children> in the same route; <Route children> will be ignored
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `<Route component={ PublicLayout }>` with `<PublicLayout>`

```
<PublicLayout>
    <Route exact path='/' component={ Main } />
    <Route exact path='/services' component={ Services } />
</PublicLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure why are you using `PublicLayout`, you can't use `Route` inside `Route`.

Create `PublicLayout` as child inside `BrowserRouter`.
`

```
<BrowserRouter>
  <div className="App">
    <Route exact path="/" component={Main} />
    <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42095600/nested-routes-in-react-router-v4). Since React v4 to wrap components you don't put anymore your Routes inside another Route, you put your Routes directly inside a component.

```
<Router>
    <MyLayout>
      <Route path='/abc' component={ABC} />
      <Route path='/xyz' component={XYZ} />
    </MyLayout>
</Router>
```