# Multiple Layouts with React Router v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I'm pulling my hair out trying to render multiple layouts with React Router v4.

For instance, I'd like pages with the following paths to have layout 1:

- exact path="/"
- path="/blog"
- path="/about"
- path="/projects"

and the following paths to have layout 2:

- path="/blog/:id
- path="/project/:id

Effectively what's being answered here but for v4: [Using multiple layouts for react-router components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33996484/using-multiple-layouts-for-react-router-components)

Comment: you will need to create a logic on top of these routes to handle which layout to display based on the path. then add the routes to that layout and render

Comment: Would be really helpful if you could submit some code demonstrating how this is achieved. @ReiDien

Answer (score 11):

None of the other answers worked so I came up with the following solution. I used the **[`render`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/render-func)** prop instead of the traditional `component` prop at the highest level.

It uses the `layoutPicker` function to determine the layout based on the path. If that path isn't assigned to a layout then it returns a "bad route" message.

```
import SimpleLayout from './layouts/simple-layout';
import FullLayout from './layouts/full-layout';

var layoutAssignments = {
  '/': FullLayout,
  '/pricing': FullLayout,
  '/signup': SimpleLayout,
  '/login': SimpleLayout
}

var layoutPicker = function(props){
  var Layout = layoutAssignments[props.location.pathname];
  return Layout ? <Layout/> : <pre>bad route</pre>;
};

class Main extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <Router>
        <Route path="*" render={layoutPicker}/>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

`simple-layout.js` and `full-layout.js` follow this format:

```
class SimpleLayout extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <div>
        <Route path="/signup" component={SignupPage}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Before anyone goes down this route, it becomes difficult when you want to use wildcard paths, e.g. '/markets/:id'

I'm sure there's a way to finagle it but I couldn't figure it out within a few minutes so I went with Nikolay's answer below

Answer (score 8):

So, for this you should use render function (https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/Route/render-func)

A really good article that helped me: https://simonsmith.io/reusing-layouts-in-react-router-4/

In the end you will be use something like this:

```
<Router>
 <div>
  <DefaultLayout path="/" component={SomeComponent} />
  <PostLayout path="/posts/:post" component={PostComponent} />
 </div>
</Router>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! the links were super useful.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem utilizing a bit of both of your solutions:

**My Routes.js file**

```
import BaseWithNav from './layouts/base_with_nav';
import BaseNoNav from './layouts/base_no_nav';

function renderWithLayout(Component, Layout) {
  return <Layout><Component /></Layout>
}

export default () => (
  <Switch>
    {/* Routes with Sidebar Navigation */}
    <Route exact path="/" render={() => renderWithLayout(Home, BaseWithNav)} />

    {/* Routes without Sidebar Navigation */}
    <Route path="/error" render={() => renderWithLayout(AppErrorMsg, BaseNoNav)} />
    <Route path="/*" render={() => renderWithLayout(PageNotFound, BaseNoNav)} />
  </Switch>
)
```

**Base.js** (where routes get imported)

```
export default class Base extends React.Component {
  render()  {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router>
          <Routes />
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

Layouts

**BaseWithNav.js**

```
class BaseWithNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {        
    return <div id="base-no-nav">
      <MainNavigation />
      <main>
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    </div>
  }
}

export default BaseWithNav;
```

**BaseNoNav.js**

```
class BaseNoNav extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let {classes} = this.props;

    return <div id="base-no-nav">
      <main>
        {this.props.children}
      </main>
    </div>
  }
}

export default BaseNoNav;
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped :)

Answer (score -2):

I know i am replying late but it's easy to do that, i hope it will helps to newbie.
i am using React 4

**Layout.js**

```
export default props => (
    <div>
        <NavMenu />
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
    </div>
);
```

**LoginLayout.js**

```
export default props => (
    <div>
        <Container>
            {props.children}
        </Container>
    </div>
);
```

Now finally we have our App

**App.js**

```
function renderWithLoginLayout(Component, Layout) {
    return <LoginLayout><Component /></LoginLayout>
}

function renderWithLayout(Path, Component, Layout) {
    return <Layout><Route path={Path} component={Component} /></Layout>
}


export default () => (
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path='/' render={() => renderWithLayout(this.path, Home, Layout)} />
        <Route path='/counter' render={() => renderWithLayout(this.path, Counter, Layout)} />
        <Route path='/fetch-data/:startDateIndex?' render={() => renderWithLayout(this.path, FetchData, Layout)} />
        <Route path='/login' render={() => renderWithLoginLayout(Login, LoginLayout)} />
    </Switch>
);
```