# Nested routes and not found route in react router dom v5

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

While trying to make nested routes in react router dom v5 I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712597/9119186) that explains how to do it very well

*(please take a look at the code here because it's a little bit difference from the answer mentioned above)*

### Layouts.js

```
const NotFound = () => <h1>Not Found</h1>;

function Layouts() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
      <Route path="/app" component={AppLayout} />
      <Route path="/" component={NotFound} />
    </Switch>
  );
}
```

### AuthLayout

```
const Signup = () => <p>Login</p>;
const Login = () => <p>Sign up</p>;

function AuthLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Auth Layout</h1>
      <Route path="/auth/signup" exact component={Signup} />
      <Route path="/auth/login" exact component={Login} />
      {/* Commenting this because I want to go to NotFound component */}
      {/* <Redirect from="/auth" to="/auth/login" exact /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### AppLayout

```
const Home = () => <p>Home</p>;
const Dashboard = () => <p>Dashboard</p>;

function AppLayout() {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>App Layout</h1>
      <Route path="/app/home" exact component={Home} />
      <Route path="/app/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
      {/* Commenting this because I want to go to NotFound component */}
      {/* Redirect from="/app" to="/app/home" exact /> */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

But this have one problem, that if you go to a route with `/app/somethingnotfound` it won't go to `<Route path="/" component={NotFound} />`, it will "stay inside" `AppLayout` and render no route.

How can I make `/app/somethingnotfound` go to `<Route path="/" component={NotFound} />` in this case?

## Edit:

Just to be more clear: I don't want to just add `<Route component={NotFound} />` inside `AuthLayout` and `AppLayout` because it will render other things. What I really need is to show the top level `NotFound`.

Answer (score 3):

Not found component usually works like this:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
    <Route exact path="/app" component={AppLayout} />
    <Route component={NotFound} />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

But you cannot mark `/auth` and `/app` as `exact` as they contain nested routes. So, you should do:

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
    <Route path="/app" component={AppLayout} />
    <Route exact path="/404" component={NotFound} />
    <Redirect to='/404' />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

and your component (e.g. `AppLayout`) with nested routes:

```
<>
<h1>App Layout</h1>
<Switch>
  <Route path="/app/home" exact component={Home} />
  <Route path="/app/dashboard" exact component={Dashboard} />
  <Redirect to="/404" />
</Switch>
</>
```

Comment: I said in the question, but I think it wasn't very clear, what I mean by "How can I make /app/somethingnotfound go to <Route path="/" component={NotFound} /> in this case?" means that I I want to show the `NotFound` component from the `Layouts` component, because the way you are doing, it's showing everything that is inside `AppLayout` (in you asnwer you removed it, but it would show `<h1>App Layout</h1>`)  which isn't what I need

Answer (score 0):

While looking in github issues I found out [this solution](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4698#issuecomment-314419439), you create a "global not found page" where you pass through the state if the route isn't found, and just render that instead of the other routes.

```
const NotFound = () => <div className="not_found"><h1>Not Found</h1></div>;

const RouteNotFound = () => <Redirect to={{ state: { notFoundError: true } }} />;

const CaptureRouteNotFound = withRouter(({children, location}) => {
  return location && location.state && location.state.notFoundError ? <NotFound /> : children;
});

const Settings = () => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/settings/account" render={() => <h1>Account Settings</h1>} />
      <Route path="/settings/profile" render={() => <h1>Profile Settings</h1>} />

      <RouteNotFound />
    </Switch>
  );
};

const AppShell = ({children}) => {
  return (
    <div className="application">
      <header>Application</header>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Application = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <CaptureRouteNotFound>
        <AppShell>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/settings" render={() => <Settings />} />
            <Route path="/profile" render={() => <h1>User Profile</h1>} />

            <RouteNotFound />
          </Switch>
        </AppShell>
      </CaptureRouteNotFound>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Route path="/" component={NotFound} />` doesn't match for all the  nested that are not implemented,  because the `Switch` in the `Layouts` component will only render the first `Route` child that matches the `pathname`. In your case, it matches the route with `AppLayout` component when you go the path `/app/somethingdoesntexist` that is why it only renders the `AppLayout` component.

**Solution**

It is better to implement a `NotFound` route for each layout using nested `Switch` components, For example

```js
function AppLayout() {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
      <Switch>
        <Route path={`${path}/home`} exact component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${path}/dashboard`} exact component={Dashboard} />
        <Route path="*" component={NotFound} />
      </Switch>
  );
}
```

In the case above we got the matched path by using `useRouteMatch` hook and nest another `Switch` component that will render any nested route that matches from the `path` and we provide a fallback `Route` specifying the path as `"*"` which will render the `NotFound` component when there is no match found.

***Here is a complete example of the solution*** [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wildflower-nlyhu?file=/src/App.js:1334-2248).

You can also see the nesting [example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/nesting) provided in the docs.

Comment: I said in the question, but I think it wasn't very clear, what I mean by "How can I make /app/somethingnotfound go to <Route path="/" component={NotFound} /> in this case?" means that I I want to show the `NotFound` component from the `Layouts` component, because the way you are doing, it's showing everything that is inside `AppLayout` (in you asnwer you removed it, but it would show `<h1>App Layout</h1>`)  which isn't what I need

Comment: Yes, it will show the `<h1>App Layout</h1>` if you render it outside the nested switch in `AppLayout`. But do you absolutely need to render the h1 outside the switch? You can make use of another route that renders the h1 inside for the base path and get the same exact result or is it not what you need. It is still a bit unclear to me what exact result you are trying to achieve. Please have a look at the codesandbox  in the answer and if it doesn't satisfy the result let me know where it  fails.

Comment: I have updated the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/jolly-wildflower-nlyhu?file=/src/App.js) in the answer. Please have a look and let me know if doesn't satisfy your need.