# Using multiple react router switch throws 404 error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to separate my routes depending on views. To be specific I have created an admin view where I am going to have different routes for admin only. I am trying to use multiple switches but I keep getting 404.

The following is how I am doing:

**App.js**

```
<div className="App">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={ AdminPanel } />
        <Route component={ NoMatch } />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

**AdminPanel.js**

```
<Link to="/admin/dashboard" className="sidebar-item">...</Link>
<Link to="/admin/dashboard/exams" className="sidebar-item">...</Link>
.
.
.
<div className="admin-content">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={ Dashboard } />
        <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/exams" component={ Exam } />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

When I visit `localhost:3000/admin/dashboard` I get to see the `Dashboard` component. But when I navigate to `localhost:3000/admin/dashboard/exams` I am greeted with the 404 page.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: this is related https://stackoverflow.com/a/56712597/3865206

Comment: @MonzoorTamal Isn't the example almost same to what I have done?

Comment: Yes. Please read those comments. You need to remove the exact.

Comment: I read but then what about when a particular route is not there? It should go to the 404 page but it doesn't.

Comment: use ``path='*'`` for 404

Comment: Nope it doesnt help.

Comment: can you please create a code snippet in sandbox. so that we can have a deep look into it.

Comment: Its just what I have shared. Nothing fancy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App.js:

```
<Switch>
    <Route path="/admin/dashboard" component={ AdminPanel } />
    <Route path="/404" component={ NoMatch } />
    <Route component={ NoMatch } />
</Switch>
```

AdminPanel.js

```
import {Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

<Switch>
    <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard" component={ Dashboard } />
    <Route exact path="/admin/dashboard/exams" component={ Exam } />
    <Route render={({location}) => <Redirect to={{
      pathname: '/404',
      state: { originalUrl: location.pathname}
    }} />} />
</Switch>
```

later in the `NoMatch` component, you can access it under `props.location.state.originUrl`

Comment: it does seem to do the trick! But I have two questions: 1) What if I would like to preserve the URL which is causing the 404? 2) Is there a way in which I don't have to explicitly mention a redirect to 404?

Comment: Using `<Route component={ NoMatch } />` renders the 404 page inside admin content container. Redirection works the way I want.

Comment: Is there a way to have only one mention of 404 to handle all no match cases? And how do I preserve the URL of not found url

Comment: what to do after accessing the `props.location.state.originUrl`?

Comment: Then you can do whatever you meant by "What if I would like to preserve the URL which is causing the 404"

Comment: Transform URL from "/404" to "/wrong-url". Possible right?

Comment: Yeah, you can name it anything, keep in mind though you gotta change matching route path as well

Comment: Check this for what I am trying to achieve: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63374142/maintain-url-in-address-bar-when-url-not-found?noredirect=1#comment112062152_63374142