# Maintain url in address bar when url not found

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am using multiple layouts and multiple react-router switches for my app. The problem that I am facing is I am not being able to maintain the wrong URL entered by the user while redirecting. How to redirect yet show the wrong URL in the address bar?

**Desirable Outcomes**

1. When user enters `/gibberish`, visit the `NotFound` page with the URL `/gibberish`.
2. When user enters `/app`, visit `/app/dashboard`.
3. When user enters `/app/gibberish` redirect to `NotFound` page with the URL `/app/gibberish`.

**Present Outcomes**

1. As desired
2. As desired
3. It redirects with the URL `/404`

**App.js**

```
<div className="App">
    <Switch>
        <Route path="/app" component={ AdminPanel } />
        <Route component={ NotFound } />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

**AdminPanel.js**

```
<div className="admin-content">
    <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/app/dashboard" component={ Dashboard } />
        <Route exact path="/app/exams" component={ Exam } />
        <Redirect exact from="/app" to="/app/dashboard" />
        <Redirect to="/404" />
    </Switch>
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a possible routing configuration. Based on the route parameters you need to programmatically render the 404 component and not redirect to it.

Comment: How do you propose to do that? And current configuration does redirect properly to the desired location but just the URL looks a bit inconsistent.

Comment: Access match: {params} from the props and check for example if "gibberish" is present (or however you want to handle this) then return the content of the 404 page. That way you're not redirecting your app and hence the URL won't change.

Comment: You want the user see admin panel layout or main layout when reaching `/app/gibberish`?

Comment: I want to simply go to my 404 page, no layout. `NotFound` is my 404 complete page.

Comment: I tried using `window.history.replaceState({}, {}, props.location.state.originalUrl);` in the constructor of `NotFound` page and it does what I aim to achieve. Yet, I feel accessing `window` is not the right way to do as in react router docs I was seeing about `history.replace` but didn't understand the way to implement.

Comment: this is actually the `hack` I was thinking about because I didn't see anywhere how to achieve this functionality without a little hack.

Comment: Any idea about the `history.replace`?