# Prevent component render in specific page react-router

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, jsx

The 'navbar' and 'footer' gets rendered on every component's page. Is there an way to prevent rendering 'footer' in the 'user' component?

> App.js

```
   <Router>
    <Route>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/About' exact component={About} />
      </Switch>
      <Footer />
    </Route>

    <Route>
      <Route path='/user' component={User} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  </Router>
```

Comment: Create two different layouts (say with footer and without footer) and use them with different pages.

Comment: Try like this https://dev.to/xavivzla/react-router-v5-multiple-layouts-4fo4

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/41683001/311255

Comment: I have edited my previous code, it is still not working. @SelvaS

Answer (score 1):

Move the `<Router>` to `index.js` file like below to get access to `props.location` inside App.js

```
<Router>
  <App />
</Router>
```

Inside your App.js file:

```
const App = ({ location }) => {
  return (
    <Route>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/About' exact component={About} />
      </Switch>
      {location.pathname !== '/user' && <Footer /> }
    </Route>
    <Route>
      <Route path='/user' component={User} />
    </Route>

    <Route path='*' component={NotFound} />
  )
}
```

This solution works with `react-router` and `react-router-dom` v5+

Comment: Can you please edit the code and explain more clearly please..